# buddypress: how do i make the group description excerpt shorter?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

i set up a theme in buddypress and i want to have a teaser section for my groups on there. it works fine but i have a problem to shorten the group description...

i'm using it like this:

```
<p><a href="<?php bp_group_permalink() ?>"><?php bp_group_name() ?></a></p>
<p><?php bp_group_description_excerpt() ?></p>
```

if theres a very long group-description it crashes my layout...
is it possible (like in wordpress) to make the excerpt shorter (with a function or something)? like maximum of 20 letters or something like that...

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put the below code into functions.php and change the length to whatever number you want.

```
// limit group description length 
function my_excerpt_group_description( $description ) {

$length = 55;
$description = substr($description,0,$length);
return $description;
}
add_filter( 'bp_get_group_description', 'my_excerpt_group_description');
```